# Buying in increments

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for the best word for when you have to buy something in increments or in certain quantity sizes.

Minimum billing, minimum charge, minimum buy is typically used when you have to spend a minimum of $X number of dollars per order.  So if the minimum buy is $50 and then unit price is $1 then you might as well buy 50 pieces.

What I am looking for is the best word or words for when items are sold in groups of X, or  packages of X?

Comment: You want *lots*, and you charge in *lot prices*.

Comment: Sometimes this is called *bulk* (vs *unit*) pricing.

Comment: Another term often used is "minimum order (value/quantity)", at least regarding your second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

- Please specify a **multiple** of $20.00 for the amount to withdraw.
- Please provide the time billed in **increments** of fifteen minutes.

Of course, if you're talking about concrete items, you will sometimes see the term used for the packaging unit.

- How many **cases** of soda?
- How many **sets** of dinnerware?
- How many **cords** of wood?

Try talking to some of the people who either sell this product or buy it and see what terminology they use.

Answer (score -1):

The expression would be **buy by weight** in case of weight, and generally **buy *something* by *something*** in general.

Comment: But the OP didn't ask about weight, but lots or collective units.

Comment: Ok, so buy by crate, box, pound, furlong, norom, etc. Depending on the mentioned X.

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants a generic word that covers all those cases, independent of X. That's the goal of the question.

Comment: I cannot think of a single word that describes that, so I have the closest possible answer. Or you could say buy by a specific amount. :)

Comment: If you don't have an answer, don't post an answer. That's all. You could add your thought about weight as a comment (but I wouldn't say "weight" is the closest possible answer: eggs are sold in dozens, but you wouldn't say you buy eggs by weight).

Comment: I edited the answer. Maybe this will be more on-topic. Weight was just an example.